# carry PHP variable value to another page and set as value of another PHP variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I'll try to explain this the best I can. I've never used sessions or cookies before, but to my understanding, sessions is the preferred choice.

1. PAGE 1 - PHP variable containing text($title). Its value is whatever the current page title is.
2. PAGE 2 - contact form(domain.com/email) where subject field value($subject) is empty, but, I want to carry the value of $title from whatever page it originated to /email, and set that value as $subject.

What I'm trying to get is for this carrying to be performed by the user through an action or hyperlink.

All I know is to start the session, session_start(), and establish values for the session on each applicable page.

From what I've read, this is what I'd do:

```
session_start()

// PAGE 1
$_SESSION['carrythis'] = $title;

// PAGE 2
$subject = $_SESSION['carrythis'];
```

But what will actually "perform" the action where the user chooses to carry the variable? I mean, in normal circumstances, I want the $subject variable to be left alone unless the user decides to use a button/link to carry the value to the new page. How can I do this?

I apologize if any of my terminology is incorrect.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying that you only want to carry the variable across to the next page if the user chooses to?

This is my backwards way of doing this (and there is likely a cleaner way that somebody else can recommend):

You could have the user check a box saying they do or don't want to carry the variable, and carry the variable across no matter what... but then on page 2, check to see if they checked the box on the form (Get), then only set the $subject to the session variable if they checked the box.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it by link without JS, since link is generated before user input.

What you can do, is to use form on first page that will submit results to second page with text input element, that will hold user's title. On second page you just have to check if submit data holds title, and if not - you will use default one.

or there is second thing - if I didn't understood you correctly and title is unchanged. Then just add it as part of the link, that user clicks, like so:

```
<a href="page2.php?title=<?php echo $title; ?>">click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create link to contact form from page 1 like this:

```
<a href="page2.php?title=current_page_title">Contact Form</a>
```

On page 2, you can retrieve the title from URL using $_GET:

```
$subject = $_GET['title'];
```

Answer (score 0):

add this to your HTML form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="carry" value="1">Carry or whatever<br>
```

and in your PHP code

```
if(isset($_POST['carry']) && $_POST['carry'] ==1){
//Do what you will do when the Stored subject
}else{
//get the subject filed Post Data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be trying to do is a POST, no need to use session for that.

Just create a form with an input field inside. Give a name to that input field, and either let the user write the content of the field or write it yourself.

The key idea is to give the user access to the  of a form that contains the data you want to pass to the PHP script.

```
// On page 1
<form method="post" action="page2.php">
  <input type="text" name="title" value=""/>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

// On page 2
$title = $_POST["title"]
```

I advice you start reading up on web development basics, like HTTP methods (POST and GET is a must, PUT and DELETE is interesting). Maybe read some basic PHP tutorials, and some javascript to sweeten the deal.